# R not recognizing if statement in creating new column

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to create a new column based on if there is a direct character match across 3 columns of the same row. I then want to put a 1 in the new column if there is a match, or a 0 if there is no match. Here's an example of the data:

```
   ID    var1   var2  var3
1     1     abc    def   abc
2     2     def    xyz   jkl
3     3     ghi    abc   abc
4     4     jkl    jkl   def
5     4     jkl    jkl   NA
...
```

Here's the code I have:

```
   prodprov$var_match <- 0
    for(i in 1:nrow(prodprov)) {
     if(prodprov$var1[i] == prodprov$var2[i] |
     prodprov$var1[i] == prodprov$var3[i] ) {
     prodprov$var_match <- 1
     }
    }
```

But I get this error:
Error in if (prodprov$var1[i] == prodprov$var2[i] |  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

The final data frame should look something like this:

```
     ID      var1  var2 var3 var_match
1     1     abc    def   abc      1
2     2     def    xyz   jkl      0
3     3     ghi    abc   abc      0
4     4     jkl    jkl   def      1
5     4     jkl    jkl   NA       1
...
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? All of these variables are the same data type (characters). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey Kayla could yo provide some data so I can work with it before I provide you a definitive answer?

Comment: Just added! Let me know if you need additional info, thank you!

Comment: Use `ifelse` for logical assignment across columns: `prodprov <- within(prodprov, { var_match <- ifelse(var1 == var2 | var1 == var3, 1, 0) })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of vectorization in R:

```
df$var_match <- df$var1 == df$var2 | df$var1 == df$var3
```

---

Result:

```
df
#   var1 var2 var3 var_match
# 1  abc  def  abc      TRUE
# 2  def  xyz  jkl     FALSE
# 3  ghi  abc  abc     FALSE
# 4  jkl  jkl  def      TRUE
# 5  jkl  jkl <NA>      TRUE
```

Input data frame for completeness:

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  var1 = c("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "jkl"),
  var2 = c("def", "xyz", "abc", "jkl", "jkl"),
  var3 = c("abc", "jkl", "abc", "def", NA)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be `Reduce` with `|`

```
as.integer(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1[-(1:2)], `==`, df1$var1)))
```

---

Or an option with `rowSums`

```
df1$var_match <- as.integer( rowSums(df1[c('var2', 'var3')] == 
             rep(df1$var1,  2)) > 0)
df1$var_match
#[1] 1 0 0 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, var1 = c("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"), 
    var2 = c("def", "xyz", "abc", "jkl"), var3 = c("abc", "jkl", 
    "abc", "def")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```